# Chat no browser desktop com aparência de mobile

Tags: suporte, layout, chat

Já faz umas semanas que algo de muito estranho aconteceu com o layout do chat para mim, ele "do nada" ficou com aparência da versão mobile. Eu cheguei a desinstalar alguns plugins que havia instalado pouco antes mas não mudou em nada.

Isso foi no Chrome, ao fazer um teste no Firefox me pareceu tudo normal, perguntei para os outros integrantes do chat e ninguém constatou o mesmo comportamento que eu.

Fiz um teste e constatei que na mesma máquina e ao mesmo tempo ao usar outro perfil de navegador no mesmo navegador e acessar o chat ele fica com a aparência normal, mas eu gostaria de mudar o layout no meu perfil do navegador que está com aparência de mobile.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Versão mobile:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Versão desktop:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: provavelmente é algo com os cookies, pois em algum momento deve ter tentado usar o device toolbar das ferramentas do chrome, talvez tenha que limpar todos cookies do dominio `chat.stackexchange.com` (e talvez `.stackexchange.com`)

Comment: como eu faço uma limpeza de cookies seletiva?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provavelmente você clicou por acidente aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basta abrir as opções, no canto superior esquerdo, e clicar em "full site":

- Clique em toogle-menu:

  [image: toogle menu]
- Depois clique em full site:

  [image: full site]

Comment: Possível que eu tenha clicado aí por acidente mesmo :O Já o Full site tava bem difícil para eu achar, rs.. mas isso definitivamente resolve a questão. Valeu!

Comment: @Math por mais tempo que se ande por aqui está-se sempre a aprender coisas novas :)